# In nifi how to iterate large json

Tags: apache-nifi, minify

In JSON I am having json structure like this,

```
{"payload":[
{"id":1,
.
.
.
},
{"id":2,
.
.
.
}
]
}
```

Like this array size is 100k. So, how can I iterate and backpressure setting that recommended to use.

Flow I am following

```
kafkaconsumer --> SplitJson --->Jolt Transform ----> Kafkaproducer
```

Is usage of SplitJSON does any performance imapact. The backpressure I am using is 1GB(default).

Comment: vikram, You wants to split the <contents{"id"....}> in payload right without affect performance?

Comment: @MahendraPrabhu Yeah, and I wanted to know is split json is the right option?

Comment: you have to use evaluate json path for get the payload <:id's> and then perform split json option. it will give better performance or if you face any performance issue then you need to split up the json data into parts the split it will lead you better results